# Аналог CROSS APPLY для Oracle 11g и его "стоимость"

Tags: sql, oracle

Задача: Найти для каждого сотрудника номер телефона из таблицы номеров. Но вывести только, если на каждого сотрудника там только один номер, иначе `null` вместо номера.

Вариант решения через `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT n.name, t.phone_num
  FROM emp_names n
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT phone_num 
                 FROM phones p
                WHERE p.name = n.name
                GROUP BY phone_num
                HAVING count(*)=1) t
```

Но такой способ не применим в 11g, т.к. там еще нет `CROSS APPLY`. Пробую вариант решения через подзапрос:

```
SELECT n.name,
       (SELECT phone_num
          FROM phones p
         WHERE p.name = n.name
         GROUP BY phone_num
        HAVING count(*)=1) phone_num
  FROM emp_names n
```

Равносильно ли это по стоимости запроса? Ведь если в таблице `emp_names` у нас имя встретится 1000 раз, то будет 1000 одинаковых подзапросов с одинаковым ответом. При этом, выдернуть из таблицы `phones` всех людей с одним номером и сджойнить тоже не вариант, т.к. таблица эта огромна.

Есть ли более экономный способ аналогичный `CROSS APPLY` для Oracle 11g?

Comment: p.s. Вопрос является упрощенной моделью к рабочей ситуации. В реальности ни один из запросов не был выполнен (возможны ошибки).

Comment: CROSS APPLY, как и коррелированный подзапрос, выполняется для каждой внешней строки. Так что чем он отличается от коррелированного запроса? ну кроме того, что подзапрос перемещается в секцию FROM, где его расположение более логично? НУ в конце концов - сравни планы для этих запросов на версии, где CROSS APPLY применим...

Comment: Akina, я не могу сравнить планы, у меня на руках только 11 оракл. Моя проблема в том, что многие подзапросы могут быть полностью одинаковыми и если есть способ не делать подзапрос 1000 раз, а просто потом брать уже найденное единожды значение, то такой способ выяснить.

Comment: Ну попробуй на любом fiddle. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18 или https://livesql.oracle.com/ ... И сразу сравни с некоррелированным запросом в CTE / подзапросе с последующим INNER JOIN. Да, некоррелированный пробуй как с группировкой, так и с 2 копиями и NOT EXISTS.

Comment: я бы еще попробовал вариант с `LEFT JOIN (SELECT phone_num
          FROM phones p
         WHERE p.name = n.name
         GROUP BY phone_num
        HAVING count(*)=1) phone_num` и сравнил план выполнения...

Comment: А почему вы сравнивает с  CROSS APPLY (скорее  всего OUTER APPLY), если он у вас недоступен?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Корреляционный подзапрос в `SELECT` клаузе (второй в вопросе), часто будет эфективней по сравнению с эквивалентным ему `OUTER JOIN` (но не всегда, зависит от данных).

Высказанное в вопросе предположение, что для 1000 одинаковых значений из внешней таблицы, подзапрос будет выполнен 1000 раз и вернёт одинаковый ответ - *неверно*. В данном случае, как раз будет преимуществом тот факт, что БД будет кешировать результат подзапроса (*Scalar Subquery Caching*). То есть, для каждого сета значений из внешней таблицы, подзапрос выполнится только один раз, а его реультат запишется во временную хэш таблицу в памяти. Для всех последующих идентичных значений, результат будет браться из этой хэш таблицы.

Небольшой пример в подтверждение вышесказанному. Подготовка схемы:

```
create table names (name) as
    select 'name1' from dual connect by level<=3
/
create table phones (name, num) as
    select 'name1','007-777/1234567' from dual  
/
create or replace function subq (s varchar2) return varchar2 as
begin
    dbms_application_info.set_client_info (userenv ('client_info')+1);
    return s;
end subq;
/
```

Следущий запрос вернёт три записи, но подзапрос будет выполнен только один раз:

```
exec dbms_application_info.set_client_info (0)
/
select n.name, (
    select subq (p.num) 
    from phones p
    where p.name = n.name 
    group BY  num having count(*) = 1) num
from names n
/
NAME  NUM             
----- ----------------
name1 007-777/1234567 
name1 007-777/1234567 
name1 007-777/1234567 

select userenv ('client_info') subqcalls from dual
/
SUBQCALLS
----------
1
```

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте сравнить с таким запросом:

```
select n.name, t.num
from names n
left join (
    select name, num 
    from phones p
    where exists (select 1
        from names n where n.name = p.name) 
    group BY name, num
    having count(*) = 1) t on t.name = n.name
/
```

---

Сравнивать планы выполнения можно, либо на реальных данных, либо на примере данных максимально приближенном к реальным. Поэтому, воздержусь от оценки запроса выше, как самого "экономичного".

Сраавнить с `CROSS APPLY` (в вопросе скорее всего речь о `OUTER APPLY`), можно с эквивалентом в 11g `LATERAL` (так как, официально не поддерживался, **только для тестовой среды**):

```
alter session set events '22829 trace name context forever';

select n.name, t.num
from names n, lateral (
    select num 
    from phones p
    where p.name = n.name
    group BY num
    having count(*) = 1)(+) t
/
```

Запросы на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7d29e6f79e6d3194687c73c84b10b97f).

Comment: К сожалению, именно про первый запрос я писал: "При этом, выдернуть из таблицы phones всех людей с одним номером и сджойнить тоже не вариант, т.к. таблица эта огромна."

Comment: Не надо сожалеть, первый запрос это только пример для сравнения. Ответ в основном после черты. Там также стоит, почему не предлагаю "единственно правильного решения".

Comment: @ВиталийЯндулов Улучшил пример с учётом последнего комментария, но опять же без утверждения, что это самое верное решение. На мой взляд лучше будет второй запрос в вопросе, т.к. предположение - _то будет 1000 одинаковых подзапросов с одинаковым ответом_, неверно, подзапрос детерминирован и будет выполнен один раз.

Answer (score 2):

Можно так попробовать

```
SELECT n.name, MAX(p.phone_num) -- идея тут взять тот единственный номер
FROM emp_names n
  LEFT JOIN phones p
    ON p.name = n.name
GROUP BY 
   n.name
HAVING count(p.phone_num)=1
```